# How to deselect/uncheck a selected item programatically in multi select ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I am having a multi-select list of tickets. So I can select multiple tickets and delete them at a time. But some particular tickets cant be deleted from the list. So I dont want to make them selected/checked in multiple select on click on that item. So I tried to deselect the particular tickets when clicking on it by using `listView.setItemChecked(position, false)` but its not working.

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
```

This method is being called on click of the items:

```
listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode,
                                              int position, long id, boolean checked) {
          System.out.println("############### Position : " +position +"  id: "+id+ " checked : "+checked );


          //Getting the ticket
           ticket = ticketList.get(position);
           if(ticket.getparticularIds()!= null && !ticket.getparticularIds().isEmpty()) {
               //***Do not select this ticket***
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Not Allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // De-selecting the particular ticket
                listView.setItemChecked(position, false);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                // Set the CAB title according to total checked items
                mode.setTitle(listView.getCheckedItemCount() + " Selected ");

            }
            else {
                 mAdapter.toggleSelection(position);

            }
            mode.setTitle(listView.getCheckedItemCount() + " Selected ");
        }
```

After Clicking on particular ticket getting this output:

```
01-16 01:48:27.254    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.254    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.284    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.284    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.304    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.304    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.324    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.334    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.334    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.364    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.374    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.374    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.394    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.414    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.424    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.444    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.454    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.474    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.484    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.494    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.514    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.524    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.534    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.544    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.554    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.564    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.574    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.574    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.584    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.584    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.594    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.614    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.614    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.624    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.634    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.644    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.654    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.674    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.684    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.694    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.704    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.704    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.714    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.724    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.734    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/System.out﹕ ############### Position : 1  id: 1 checked : false
01-16 01:48:27.734    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: stack overflow on call to Landroid/util/ContainerHelpers;.binarySearch:ILII
01-16 01:48:27.744    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/dalvikvm﹕ method requires 32+20+0=52 bytes, fp is 0xb0282330 (48 left)
01-16 01:48:27.744    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/dalvikvm﹕ expanding stack end (0xb0282300 to 0xb0282000)
01-16 01:48:27.744    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android I/dalvikvm﹕ Shrank stack (to 0xb0282300, curFrame is 0xb0282604)
01-16 01:48:27.744    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
01-16 01:48:27.744    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1a6eba8)
01-16 01:48:27.894    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1635K, 9% free 20465K/22260K, paused 40ms, total 41ms
01-16 01:48:28.014    1426-1426/com.demo.lv.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.demo.lv.android, PID: 1426
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #27: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:670)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:245)
            at com.demo.lv.android.activities.TicketListFragment$2.onItemCheckedStateChanged(TicketListFragment.java:231)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onItemCheckedStateChanged(AbsListView.java:6364)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.setItemChecked(AbsListView.java:1026)
            at com.demo.lv.android.activities.TicketListFragment$2.onItemCheckedStateChanged(TicketListFragment.java:233)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onItemCheckedStateChanged(AbsListView.java:6364)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.setItemChecked(AbsListView.java:1026)
            at com.demo.lv.android.activities.TicketListFragment$2.onItemCheckedStateChanged(TicketListFragment.java:233)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onItemCheckedStateChanged(AbsListView.java:6364)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.setItemChecked(AbsListView.java:1026)
            at com.demo.lv.android.activities.TicketListFragment$2.onItemCheckedStateChanged(TicketListFragment.java:233)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onItemCheckedStateChanged(AbsListView.java:6364)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.setItemChecked(AbsListView.java:1026)
            at com.demo.lv.android.activities.TicketListFragment$2.onItemCheckedStateChanged(TicketListFragment.java:233)
            at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onItemCheckedStateChanged(AbsListView.java:6364)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.setItemChecked(AbsListView.java:1026)
```

This is all I have done but its not working for me. How can I solve it???

Comment: instead of listView.setItemChecked(position, checked); you have to use listView.setItemChecked(position, false)

Comment: sorry @EagleEye .... it was listView.setItemChecked(position, false) only there, I just changed it for testing .... false is also not working...

Comment: Is control goes inside if condition?

Comment: yes its going inside if

Comment: Among perhaps other things, get rid of `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, as you are not changing the data in the adapter.

Comment: @CommonsWare ... actually its not reaching up to  `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, it is again calling back `onItemCheckedStateChanged()` method somewhere inside `listView.setItemChecked()`. you can see the output there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution incase any one need to know, problem is again calling back onItemCheckedStateChanged() method because of

`listView.setItemChecked(position, false);`

it will set that position selected item to false then it will call again onItemCheckedStateChanged() and this time value is false. so it will shows stack overflow error or inside infinite loop calling same function.
so need to replace with this code.

```
if (listView.isItemChecked(position))
                listView.setItemChecked(position, false);
```

It must work like charm.